# LANG 環境変数と日本語表示について

Tags: linux, 日本語

ある Linux 環境では日本語が表示できておらず、調べたところ環境変数の LANG の指定が必要という情報を見つけました。
`C.UTF-8` を `ja_JP.UTF-8` にしたところ、日本語は表示できたのですが、この設定をすることで `ls -l` の日付部分や `date` コマンドの出力まで日本語になってしまいます。
これまで問題なく使えていた環境の設定を確認すると、 `C.UTF-8` なのに日本語が表示できています。
コマンドの出力は英語のままとして、日本語を表示するにはどうすればよいでしょうか？

環境変数を設定していない状態で、日本語が表示される環境とされない環境の `locale` コマンドの結果はどちらも以下のとおりでした。

```
LANG=C.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="C.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="C.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="C.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="C.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="C.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="C.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="C.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

環境によっては `LANGUAGE=` の行があるものもありました。

また、 `localectl status` で得られる System Locale はどちらも `ja_JP.utf8` でした。

一応接続方法についてですが、すべて同じクライアントから ssh で接続しています。

Comment: ロケールの設定状況を確認したいので、`locale` コマンドの実行結果を追記していただけますか。

Comment: > `コマンドの出力は英語のままとして、日本語を表示するにはどうすればよいでしょうか？`

矛盾するように感じるのですが、デスクトップ環境等で日本語を表示したい、ということでしょうか？

Comment: 個人的な環境(Ubuntu Linux 21.04)では `LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8` として `LC_TIME` と `LC_MESSAGES` を `C` に設定しています。これで日付(時刻)の表示や gettext に対応しているコマンドが出力するメッセージ(ヘルプメッセージやメニュー文字列など)は英語表記になります。既にご存知かもしれませんが、`LC_*` の説明は `man 7 locale` で確認できます。

Comment: 「デスクトップ環境等で日本語を表示したい、ということでしょうか？」についてですが、 ssh 接続しているターミナル上でです。
日本語ファイルを cat や less などで表示したり、エディタ上で日本語を入力した場合に表示できないので、これを表示できるようにするのが目的です。

Comment: LC_TIME と LC_MESSAGES だけを C にする方法は試してみたいと思いますが、他の環境ではすべて C になっていても日本語が表示できているのでできればそれに合わせたいと考えています。